# Integrated Google, Gmail, Google Docs, Calendar Search

Tags: gmail, google-search

I swear there was a point where Google would at least occasionally return matches to my personal data, e.g., the contents of a personal Gmail message. Was this really the case at one point? Was it experimental/discontinued?

Is there a third-party app or plugin that similarly integrates a search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google does allow you to include results from your personal data (if you've allowed Google to do this) with some of Google's products including Google Calendar and Gmail, but you have to be explicit, such as `my email lisa dinner`. It apparently doesn't search through Google Drive or Docs. From [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1710607):

You can search for information from other Google products you use, like Gmail or Google Calendar. Try searching for upcoming flights, restaurant reservations, or appointments.

**Example searches**
Note: Some examples may not work in certain regions.

- Events: Find Google Calendar events and appointments by searching my events .
- Bills: Find your bills by searching for my bills. You can also search for specific types of bills, or bills from a certain time. For example, my comcast bills 2018.
- Packages: Find out when your package will arrive by searching my packages.
- Reservations: Find your restaurant or hotel reservations by searching my reservations.
- Flights: Find your upcoming flights to get up-to-date information by searching my flights.
- Google Photos: Find photos from your Google Photos by searching my photos or my photos from New York in 2019.